# Laravel 8: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::sync()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a project in Laravel 8 and in this project which is a Movie Storage, I have **Many To Many** relationship between the `movies` table and `actors` table.

So in order to adjust that Relationship, I've added these to the Models:

`Actor.php`:

```
public function movies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Movie::class);
}
```

`Movie.php`:

```
public function actors() {
    return $this->hasMany(Actor::class);
}
```

And the Migration for `actor_movie` which is the pivot table goes here:

```
Schema::create('actor_movie', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('actor_id');
    $table->foreign('actor_id')->references('id')->on('actors')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('movie_id');
    $table->foreign('movie_id')->references('id')->on('movies')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['actor_id','movie_id']);
});
```

And now at my form for inserting new movie, I've added a select option to retrieve all the current actors from the DB and therefore I can select multiple actors, like this:

```
<select name="actors[]" class="form-control" id="actor" multiple>
    @foreach(App\Models\Actor::all() as $actor)
        <option value="{{ $actor->id }}">{{ $actor->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And on the Controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $movie = new Movie();
    $movie->director_id = $request->director;
    $movie->name = $request->name;
    $movie->link = $request->link;
    $movie->year = $request->year;
    $movie->starred = $request->starred;
    $movie->watched = $request->watched;
    $movie->save();

    if(!is_null($movie)) {
        $imdb = new Imdb();
        $imdb->rate = $request->imdb;
        $imdb->movie_id = $movie->id;
        $imdb->save();
    }

   $movie->actors()->sync(request('actors'));
   return view('/admin/movies');
```

}

As you can see `$movie->actors()->sync(request('actors'));` should sync the `actor_id` and `movie_id` of that table. But it retuns this error instead:

```
> **BadMethodCallException** Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::sync()
```

So what is going wrong here? How can I sync my `actor_movie` table properly?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class);
    }
```

Movie.php:

```
public function actors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Actor::class);
    }
```

in many-to-many relationship we must use `belongsToMany()`

Answer (score 2):

As it's a many-to-many relationship in both functions you need to use `belongsToMany`, so you should use:

**Actor.php:**

```
public function movies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class);
}
```

Instead of:

```
public function movies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Movie::class);
}
```

**Movie.php:**

```
public function actors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Actor::class);
}
```

Instead of:

```
public function actors() {
    return $this->hasMany(Actor::class);
}
```

`sync()` works only for many to many relationships.